# installing home brew for rails 3.2

Tags: osx-lion, ruby-on-rails-3.2, homebrew

I am trying to install homebrew according to the guidelines described in [here](http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/).

I have curl and rvm, and want to install rails 1.9.3 on my lion 1.7.4 with Xcode 4.3.2 and with developer command line tools installed.

It seems I will need libksba, which requires me to use to command  `brew install libksba`.
So I will need Home Brew.

I follow the instructions and use 
`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"`

which outputs the following:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/Formula/...
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/...

Press enter to continue
==> Downloading and Installing Homebrew...
==> Installation successful!
You should run `brew doctor' *before* you install anything.
Now type: brew help
[~]$ 
[~]$ 
[~]$ brew doctor
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/tab.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- ostruct `(LoadError)`
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/tab.rb:1
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/bottles.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/bottles.rb:1
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:1
    from /usr/local/bin/brew:10:in `require'
    from /usr/local/bin/brew:10
[~]$
```

So this means basically that brew was not installed right. Do I have to change the path at which it is looking for? I used to have MacPorts in, which I completely erased so there should be no conflicts there. Please help!!! Thanks a lot! It's an awesome community.

---

UPDATE:

I time machined back a year because I thought I did something critically wrong. Now I still have an issue installing, but it seems a bit more common.

I installed homebrew using

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

Any command of "brew" gives me this error:

```
[~]$ brew
/usr/local/bin/brew:6:in `require': no such file to load -- pathname (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/brew:6
```

Any suggestions? Thank you all!

Comment: I've got the same problem, I even tried to remove homebrew and start over but commands like brew --prefix return the same ostruct error above

Comment: I know, it seems brew command itself has trouble. I hope there is someone out there who can help. Thanks for letting me know I am not the only one.

Comment: My case is strange, because i had to upgrade xcode (i had no default system ruby which homebrew requires), also i am on snow leopard

Comment: FYI it's not the exact same issue, but I am continuing a thread in github that may help.

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12522#issuecomment-6070882

Comment: Thanks all for commenting, I reinstalled everything and made many updates, I dont know why but its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as mentioned in my comment above.  To resolve it I ended up having to restore my default system ruby.  I am on SnowLeopard - OSX 10.6.8, so your resources may vary, but what I did was:

- uninstall xcode: sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
- rsync or copy /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework from another machine running 10.6.8
- You also need the ruby executables in /usr/bin to point to the system Ruby: /usr/bin/{erb,gem,irb,rdoc,ri,ruby,testrb}
- these are just symlinks to /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework
- erb -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/erb
- so I re-symlinked them, for example from /usr/bin: sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/erb ./erb
- the brew executable currently uses /usr/bin/ruby so that needs to be there in the least
- I hear future versions of brew will point directly at the system ruby on the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework path, so symlinking ruby to a custom install is a bad idea

At this point brew commands worked again and ostruct (part of ruby standard lib) was again found.  I went ahead and added xcode back in and worked through some minor 'brew doctor' errors.

I have now replaced all my old macports packages with homebrew packages and its such an improvement!

Comment: glad it works for you.It seems like it has to do with the default os ruby. If you try to mess with it it gives you errors like this one.
Thanks for your input, it definitely has to do with restoring the os, and getting xcode to work properly.
How did you make sure all macport files are removed? is there an easy way?

Comment: I followed these directions but had to do a bit more with making sure all the packages were completely uninstalled before removing macports itself: http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html